# Unicode characters output from python I/O to files

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I don't know if this is my misunderstanding of UTF-8 or of python, but I'm having trouble understanding how python writes Unicode characters to a file. I'm on a Mac under OSX by the way, if that makes a difference.

Let's say I have the following unicode string

`foo=u'\x93Stuff in smartquotes\x94\n'`

Here \x93 and \x94 are those awful smart-quotes.

Then I write it to a file:

`with open('file.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(foo.encode('utf8'))`

When I open the file in a text editor like TextWrangler or in a web browser `file.txt` seems like it was written as

> \xc2\x93**Stuff in smartquotes\xc2\x94\n

The text editor properly understands the file to be UTF8 encoded, but it renders \xc2\x93 as garbage. If I go in and manually strip out the \xc2 part, I get what I expect, and TextWrangler and Firefox render the utf characters as smartquotes.

This is exactly what I get when I read the file back into python without decoding it as 'utf8'. However, when I do read it in with the `read().decode('utf8')` method, I get back what I originally put in, without the \xc2 bit.

This is driving me bonkers, because I'm trying to parse a bunch of html files into text and the incorrect rendering of these unicode characters is screwing up a bunch of stuff.

I also tried it in python3 using the read/write methods normally, and it has the same behavior.

**edit**: Regarding stripping out the \xc2 manually, it turns out that it was rendering correctly when I did that because the browser and text editors were defaulting to Latin encoding.

Also, as a follow up, Filefox renders the text as

> ☐Stuff in smartquotes☐

where the boxes are empty unicode values, while Chrome renders the text as

> Stuff in smartquotes

Comment: Did you tell your text editor or web browser that it's supposed to read the file as UTF-8?

Comment: I manually set both the text editors and web browsers to read the file as UTF-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, `u'\x93'` and `u'\x94'` are not the Unicode codepoints for smart quotes.  They are smart quotes in the [`Windows-1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding, which is not the same as the [`latin1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding.  In `latin1`, those values are not defined.

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.name(u'\x93')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: no such name
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.name(u'\x94')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: no such name
>>> ud.name(u'\u201c')
'LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK'
>>> ud.name(u'\u201d')
'RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK'
```

So you should one of:

```
foo = u'\u201cStuff in smartquotes\u201d'
foo = u'\N{LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK}Stuff in smartquotes\N{RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK}'
```

or in a UTF-8 source file:

```
#coding:utf8
foo = u'“Stuff in smartquotes”'
```

**Edit:** If you somehow have a Unicode string with those incorrect bytes in it, here's a way to fix them.  The first 256 Unicode codepoints map 1:1 with `latin1` encoding, so it can be used to encode a mis-decoded Unicode string directly back to a byte string so the correct decoding can be used:

```
>>> foo = u'\x93Stuff in smartquotes\x94'
>>> foo
'\x93Stuff in smartquotes\x94'
>>> foo.encode('latin1').decode('windows-1252')
'\u201cStuff in smartquotes\u201d'
>>> print foo
“Stuff in smartquotes”
```

If you have the UTF-8-encoded version of the incorrect Unicode characters:

```
>>> foo = '\xc2\x93Stuff in smartquotes\xc2\x94'
>>> foo = foo.decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('windows-1252')
>>> foo
u'\u201cStuff in smartquotes\u201d'
>>> print foo
“Stuff in smartquotes”
```

And if you have the very worst case the following Unicode string:

```
>>> foo = u'\xc2\x93Stuff in smartquotes\xc2\x94'
>>> foo.encode('latin1') # back to a UTF-8 encoded byte string.
'\xc2\x93Stuff in smartquotes\xc2\x94'
>>> foo.encode('latin1').decode('utf8') # Undo the UTF-8, but Unicode is still wrong.
u'\x93Stuff in smartquotes\x94'
>>> foo.encode('latin1').decode('utf8').encode('latin1') # back to a byte string.
'\x93Stuff in smartquotes\x94'
>>> foo.encode('latin1').decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('windows-1252') # Now decode correctly.
u'\u201cStuff in smartquotes\u201d'
```

Comment: I'm not trying to write proper unicode per se, I'm actually trying to parse some existing html which was probably converted from an MS Word doc or something. I think you're party right, but if I write `file.write(foo.encode('latin1'))` then the text is properly rendered in latin or western encoding. It appears to be latin encoding. What's the proper way of handling this type of thing?

Comment: @WildGunman, it's not `latin1` encoding, but `windows-1252`.  See my edit above.  You may be encoding that incorrect Unicode string in `latin1` but if you are seeing smart quotes then you are viewing the file in `Windows-1252`.  Are you looking at the file in Windows?  It would display a file in `Windows-1252` even if encoded in `latin1` and `\x93` and `\x94` as smart quotes.

Comment: Also, the term for what you have is [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Comment: Holy heckballs. I feel like people's annoyance with Unicode has less to do with either UTF8 or ascii being so terrible, and more to do with the intermediate encodings causing such non-stop pain parade for both.